# access network computer through real IP

Tags: remote-desktop, ipv4

I am have internet connection in my home. my ISP provide a router with real IP 174.xxx.xxx.xxx and my desktop and laptop connected with router. my desktop connected with that router IP 192.168.2.1. now i want to access my desktop from my Office located different state. how can i do this? anyone can help?

Comment: You computer is hidden behind the router, it doesn't have direct access from the internet, you could use solution like TeamViewer (https://www.teamviewer.com/en/) for such a task easily

Comment: You would have to forward all traffic on the desired port to `192.168.2.1` to acomplish your goals to access it the PC outside of your intranet network.

Comment: to add my 2cents: after you figure out @Ramhound 's solution - be aware that some ISPs change your external IP and provide a payed service to have a static IP. And then, there are some who do not do that. If on dynamic  there are services which provide dynamic DNS. I had a provider which changed my IP every 24 hours and I had some providers which do not change my external IP at all.